# operator > overloading is not working

Tags: c++, oop, c++11

Previously I have overloaded `operator <` and I have sorted a structure.

Now I am trying to overload `operator >` but it doesn't work (actually doesn't even compile). I need some help to find out the queries.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
struct a
{
    int num1;
    int num2;
    bool operator > (const a& rhs) const
    {
        return  num1>rhs.num1;
    }
};

int main()
{
    a array[1000];
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        cin>>array[i].num1>>array[i].num2;
    }
    sort(array, array+2);
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        cout<<array[i].num1<<" "<<array[i].num2<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `but i did not worked` Care to elaborate.

Comment: `bits/stdc++.h ` should not be used in user code. I think it is an internal implementation header. Also, define the `operator>` as a free method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When looking at [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) we can see when using the overload with 2 parameters:

> 1) Elements are compared using operator<

This means that if your custom type does not define `operator<` you will get a compiler error. You can use a custom comparator as the third parameter if you don't want to overload this operator. Alternatively you could just invert the result of your `operator>`:

```
bool operator < (const a& rhs) const
{
   return !(num1>rhs.num1);
}
```

Comment: as i have overloaded the operator < then i thought it would be possible to overload operator >...i did not get u much in your answer .will u please be more elaborate

Comment: @leonelshovo I can't see your overload of that operator in your code.

Comment: @leonel: `std:sort()` needs `operator<` to be implemented; it does not care about `operator>`; if you need a reverted sorting, you can implement `operator<` as suggested by Gill, `std:sort()` will not complain if the operator actually act as `operator<`.

Comment: @shrike i have got it and now i also understood the concept of  given at the very beginning

Comment: Implementing the less than operator as the inversion of the greater than operator is wrong. Consider the case where num1 == rhs.num1. Both operators need to return false then.